# Consolidating Android unit test reports into single location

Tags: android, unit-testing, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

For the ease of copying the test reports to the CI, I wanted to copy all the unit test reports across my various modules to a single directory. Since Gradle's `test-report-aggregation` plugin doesn't work for Android projects I tried to roll something myself which sort of works.

### project level build.gradle.kts

```
val debugTestReport: TaskProvider<TestReport> =
    tasks.register<TestReport>("debugTestReport") {
        destinationDirectory.set(file("$buildDir/reports/debug"))

        // Combine all 'test' task results into a single HTML report
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        reportOn(subprojects.map {
            it.tasks.withType(Test::class).filter { test -> test.name == "testDebugUnitTest" }
        }
        )
    }

val releaseTestReport: TaskProvider<TestReport> =
    tasks.register<TestReport>("releaseTestReport") {
        destinationDirectory.set(file("$buildDir/reports/release"))

        // Combine all 'test' task results into a single HTML report
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        reportOn(subprojects.map {
            it.tasks.withType(Test::class).filter { test -> test.name == "testReleaseUnitTest" }
        })
    }

tasks.register<TestReport>("testReport") {
    dependsOn(debugTestReport, releaseTestReport)
}

subprojects {
    project.plugins.configure(project = project)
    // Don't create the reports if we're running from the IDE, ideally we'd only generate the
    // reports for complete test runs anyway
    if (properties.containsKey("android.injected.invoked.from.ide")) return@subprojects
    // Check that we're not running verifyPaparazziDebug or recordPaparazziDebug
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.none { it.matches(Regex(".*[v|r][a-z]*P[a-z]*D.*")) }) {
        tasks.withType<Test> {
            val reports =
                if (name == "testDebugUnitTest") debugTestReport else releaseTestReport
            finalizedBy(reports)
            ignoreFailures = true
            testLogging {
                events("failed")
            }
            exclude("**/design/snapshot/**")
        }
    }
}
```

This works when I run debugUnitTest or releaseUnitTest but it would be better if it would just consolidate the reports of whatever tests were actually run. So if I said `app:debugUnitTest` it would just copy all the debug test reports for the app module tests that were run, rather than also running the tests in `module1` etc.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

NEW ANSWER USING THIRD PARTY GRADLE PLUGIN:
I actually manage to fix the issue of duplicate execution of test using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73405558)

In your `build.gradle` project level, add the below code.

```
plugins {
    base
    id("io.github.gmazzo.test.aggregation.coverage") version "2.2.0"
    id("io.github.gmazzo.test.aggregation.results") version "2.2.0"
}


testAggregation {
    modules { // add your target module here
        include(project(":app:"), project(":app:libs:module1"), project(":app:libs:module2"))
        exclude(rootProject)
    }
    coverage {
        exclude( // Lets you exclude some part of the code on coverage report 
            // Android
            "**/R.class",
            "**/R$*.class",
            "**/BuildConfig.*",
            "**/Manifest*.*",
            "**/*Test*.*",
            "android/**/*.*",
            // DataBinding/ViewBinding
            "android/databinding/**/*.class",
            "**/android/databinding/*Binding.class",
            "**/android/databinding/*",
            "**/androidx/databinding/*",
            "**/BR.*",
            "**/databinding/*Binding.class",
            // Dagger
            "**/*_MembersInjector.class",
            "**/Dagger*Component.class",
            "**/Dagger*Component${'$'}Builder.class",
            "**/Dagger*Subcomponent*.class",
            "**/*Subcomponent${'$'}Builder.class",
            "**/*Module_*Factory.class",
            "**/di/module/*",
            "**/*_Factory*.*",
            "**/*Module*.*",
            "**/*Dagger*.*",
            "**/*Hilt*.*",
            // Kotlin
            "**/*MapperImpl*.*",
            "**/*${'$'}ViewInjector*.*",
            "**/*${'$'}ViewBinder*.*",
            "**/*Component*.*",
            "**/*${'$'}Lambda$*.*",
            "**/*Companion*.*",
            "**/*MembersInjector*.*",
            "**/*_Provide*Factory*.*",
            "**/*Extensions*.*",
            // Sealed and data classes
            "**/*${'$'}Result.*",
            "**/*${'$'}Result$*.*",
            // Adapters generated by moshi
            "**/*JsonAdapter.*",
        )
    }
}

tasks.check {
    dependsOn(tasks.jacocoAggregatedCoverageVerification)
}
```

Then add the following on each module level `build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            enableUnitTestCoverage = true 
        }
        release {
            aggregateTestCoverage = false // This prevents duplication of unit test result
        }
}
```

Then run `./gradlew jacocoAggregatedReport` for code coverage report or `./gradlew testAggregatedReport` for unit test report

NEW ANSWER USING CUSTOM GRADLE TASK:
The below Gradle task should do the work.

```
Groovy

    task testReport(type: TestReport) {
      destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/allTests")
      // Combine all 'test' task results into a single HTML report
      reportOn subprojects.collect { it.tasks.withType(Test) }
    }


Kotlin DSL (Tested)

    tasks.register<TestReport>("testReport") {
    destinationDirectory.set(file("$rootDir/reports/tests/unitTest"))
    // Combine all 'test' task results into a single HTML report
    testResults.from(subprojects.flatMap { it.tasks.withType(Test::class) })
    }
```

Then execute

```
./gradlew testReport
```

Note: Add this in the project level `build.gradle` not in the module level, however if you wanted it in app level then use `allprojects` instead of `subprojects`. Unfortunately the tests are being duplicated, I don't have any solution as of the moment. My guess is due to both release and debug test being run, feel free to improve my answer.

OLD ANSWER:
If I understand correctly you are looking for [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#multi-module-reports-instrumented-tests) where all module unit test and instrumented test report are in single location.

There is a reported issue already in Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222730176). The workaround is to add the below line before the apply plugin.

`subprojects.forEach { evaluationDependsOn(it.path) }`

It should look like this if you are using Version Catalog with Kotlin DSL.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // Add open source licenses notice
        classpath(libs.oss.licenses.plugin)
    }
}

subprojects.forEach { evaluationDependsOn(it.path) }

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.kotlin) apply false
    alias(gms.plugins.google.services) apply false
    alias(firebase.plugins.crashlytics) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp) apply false
}
apply(plugin = "android-reporting")
```

Running `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest mergeAndroidReports --continue` should now generate the report in `path_to_your_project/build/`

Comment: I can't seem to get that working? Perhaps because of the TOML config on my project? But no matter where I put the plugin the project level gradle file it complains about it.

Comment: I can't make it work with Version Catalog as well, instead what I did is to follow what is in the documentation which is not using plugin block and alias. Probably JaCoCo plugin is a better solution?

Comment: @BarryIrvine can you try the updated answer to see if it solves your problem?